# 'WindowsError: [Error 2]' while iterating files in C:\\ using 'os.walk'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-os

I'm trying to make a program which iterates over every file in my C drive, 
checking the file's size and 
appending the size value to the list named 'filesizes_stored'.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import collections

filesizes_stored = []

for (path, dir, files) in os.walk("c:/"):
    for filename in files:
        print unicode(os.path.join(path, filename), 'cp949')
        # print os.path.getsize(unicode(os.path.join(path, filename)))
        filesizes_stored.append(
            os.path.getsize(
                unicode(
                    os.path.expandvars(
                        os.path.expanduser(
                            os.path.join(path, filename))),'cp949'))/1024.0)

print len(filesizes_stored)
```

I have written this script in python 2.7, and my computer's OS is Windows 7.

When I execute this script, the execution process goes on smoothly for some time, working successfully for most of the files, but then the execution stops with an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kim/PycharmProjects/filesize_gatherer/gather_filesize.py", line 15, in <module>
    os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(path, filename))), 'cp949'))/1024.0)
File "C:\Users\Kim\Anaconda2\lib\genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError c:/Users\Kim\AppData\Local\Temp\$$$52FE.tmp
: [Error 2] : u'c:/Users\\Kim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\$$52FE.tmp'
```

I'm suspecting the '$$$' part of the filename to be the source of the problem..

Comment: I would imagine that the underlying temporary file was deleted between the getting the list of files and then getting details (`stat`) about that file.